# Mathematical comparison of cellars and rabbit holes primarily in a topological perspective?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I am interested in the mathematical difference between cellars and rabbit holes, especially from a topological perspective. A cellar is an underground structure that is used for storing food, while a rabbit hole is an entrance to a tunnel system where rabbits live. Both have holes that allow access to the underground space, but they may have different shapes and sizes of holes. I want to know how topology can help me compare and classify these shapes and sizes. For example, how can I use the concept of homeomorphism to determine if two shapes are topologically equivalent? How can I measure the number and dimension of holes in a shape? How can I deform a shape into another shape without cutting or gluing? I am asking this question out of curiosity and for educational purposes. I would appreciate any answer that can explain the basic ideas and methods of topology in relation to cellars and rabbit holes.

I would also be interested in how other fields of mathematics can be applied to cellars and rabbit holes. For example, can I make a geometric definition of them to compare them and help me study the shapes, sizes of these spaces? Could algebra help me describe the patterns and structures of these spaces? Could calculus help me analyze the changes and variations of these spaces? Could  probability help me estimate the chaotic possibilities of these spaces? I am open to any suggestions or insights that can show me the connections and applications of mathematics to cellars and rabbit holes.

Comment: Before anyone asks this question come up as a joke but it we couldn't give it a clear answer ourself

Comment: Look up the Euler Characteristic of a surface. You might also look into Knot Theory.

Comment: The Euler Characteristics (χ = V − E + F) seems like a dead end. If we say that the rabbit hole is either a sphere or a cylinder it will get 2-N or 0-N.

Comment: I think the domain you should look is "**mathematical morphology**" ; it is a rather new domain, elaborated in the 1960s-1980s with operations like eroding (thinning), enlarging (dilation), connecting,  "percolation", etc... It looks especialy adapted to what you are looking for